# JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a '$$prop_def' property

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Hello i'm trying to use this package https://github.com/beyonk-adventures/svelte-facebook-pixel to add tracking to my ecommerce website

```
import FacebookPixel from '@beyonk/svelte-facebook-pixel';
    
    let fb;
    let pixelId = '1893777930777627';

    
    
</script>

<FacebookPixel bind:this={fb} id={pixelId} />
```

[image]

And i have this error, if someone can help me? Thanks!